# Best way to manage many projects using your own nuget packages?

Tags: git, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have recently made some libraries that I use in all of my code to give some common functionality. I have rolled them into NuGet packages and released the projects on Github as well.

Some of the projects that use these libraries are also on Github.

Here is the problem. I want the projects to be completely stand alone when built and uploaded to Github, so for that push I want to use the Nuget reference installed.

When I am adding new features to my libraries and debugging with the projects, I want the reference to be to the library project so I can debug the code of the library from within the project debugger.

I know I can switch the reference back and forth, but that clutters up the git repo, and is also harder to maintain than I would like.

Is there some common pattern that I have not found to deal with this in a easy manner?

Thanks for any input!
John Vickers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some common pattern that I have not found to deal with this
>   in a easy manner?

To my knowledge, we could not easily switch directly between nuget reference and project reference.

In general, the project-to-project reference should be recommend when the referenced project is modified frequently, the nuget reference is more appropriate when share the reference project to others or publish it. So when we developing and debugging libraries, we will use the project reference, when we share and publish project, we will convert project references to nuget reference.

Besides, there is a Visual Studio extension [NuGet Reference Switcher](https://github.com/rsuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher), which can help you automatically switches NuGet assembly references to project references and vice-versa.

> This is useful when developing applications which reference own NuGet
>   packages: When developing an application, switch to project references
>   so that all code is editable and debuggable. After finishing the
>   development, create new NuGet package versions, switch back to NuGet
>   references and upgrade to the new NuGet versions.

Hope this helps.